# Variable mysteriously disappears? AWS CodeBuild

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

What follows is my buildspec.yml

```
build:
        commands:
            - 'IMAGE_TAG=$(cat package.json | grep version | head -1 | awk -F: ''{ print $2 }'' | sed ''s/[",]//g'')'
            - echo $IMAGE_TAG
            - docker build -t $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .
            - docker tag $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
```

Here's the output from the relevant build:

```
 [Container] 2018/12/12 22:06:42 Running command IMAGE_TAG=$(cat package.json | grep version | head -1 | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/[",]//g')
 [Container] 2018/12/12 22:06:42 Running command echo $IMAGE_TAG <<< GOOD
1.0.0                           <<<< PERFECT
 [Container] 2018/12/12 22:06:42 Running command docker build -t $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .
invalid argument "gotbot-air:" for t: invalid reference format
See 'docker build --help'.     <<<<<< OH NO
 [Container] 2018/12/12 22:06:42 Command did not exit successfully docker build -t $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG . exit status 125
```

As you can clearly see on the marked lines, somehow the variable $IMAGE_TAG is set correctly to 1.0.0 when echo'd, yet on the very next line of execution in my build script, it seems to have disappeared.

Please note I am using version 0.2 of the specification.

EDIT: It may be important that my other environment variables are either declared at the top in `env` or native code build variables, it might be that im getting some different execution environment when running the docker command?

Comment: How are you gathering that the IMAGE_TAG is the piece that is wrong here? You are receiving an invalid argument for "gotbot-air", I don't see how that ties in with the 1.0.0 variable? What is gotbot-air?

Comment: "gotbot-air" is the value of the variable $IMAGE_REPO_NAME.

Docker is complaining because `-t gotbot-air:` is not a valid argument. I intended for it to be `-t gotbot-air:1.0.0`, which would be valid.

Comment: Okay why don't you try:

`IMAGE_TAG=$(cat package.json | grep version | head -1 | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/[",]//g') && docker build -t $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG . `

See if that fixes it, if so then state is not being passed correctly somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the version of your BuildSpec file. Change it to version: 0.2.

In version 0.1, AWS CodeBuild runs each build command in a separate instance of the default shell in the build environment. In version 0.2, AWS CodeBuild runs all build commands in the same instance of the default shell in the build environment.

Comment: My buildspec is definitely on 0.2... If it weren't, the echo in between shouldn't work right?