# AWS CodeBuild: Where is documented buildspec.yml multiline command script?

Tags: aws-codebuild

I have buildspec.yml with multiple commands in `pre_build` phase and more in `build` phase. When I specify commands as array items

```yaml
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - $Env:TEST_SUBFOLDER='dev\';
      - Invoke-Expression('cmd /c set')
```

each command is executed in its own shell session. In above example `TEST_SUBFOLDER` environment variable is not set when invoking next command.
But if I specify commands as single item

```yaml
  pre_build:
    commands:
      $Env:TEST_SUBFOLDER='dev\'; `
      Invoke-Expression('cmd /c set')
```

every command runs in same shell and `TEST_SUBFOLDER` environment variable is set.
Where is this feature documented? I do not find any reference.
SO question [Variable mysteriously disappears? AWS CodeBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53752225/variable-mysteriously-disappears-aws-codebuild) sugests to use version 0.2 of buildspec. I am using version 0.2

Answer (score 7):

You can do a [YAML block scalar syntax](https://yaml-multiline.info/):

```yaml
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - >-
        $Env:TEST_SUBFOLDER='dev\';
        Invoke-Expression('cmd /c set')
```

Comment: Worth mentioning: yours is correct, but indentation matters. Extra/irregular indentation will result in line-splitting, which is undesirable if you expect this to run as one command.